# FindElements timeout behaviour when using ImplicitWait

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, dc);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
** Search google and end up at a Google Search Results page
List<IWebElement> elements = new List<IWebElement>();
elements.AddRange(driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"vn1s0p1c0\"]")));
```

When I run this, it works if the XPath exists on the page, but if that Xpath does not exist on the page, it will wait and then timeout at 60 seconds. I though the behaviour of FindElements was to return an empty list if the element is not found. No idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with specifying 60 second time to wait for searching that element. If you remove second line code which is setting waiting time, then it will returns empty list of `IWebElement` if that element do not exist in the driver page. Otherwise, with specifying 60 second to search for that element will throw `Timeout exception` after 60 second.

Following code would skip timeout issue :

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, dc);
** Search google and end up at a Google Search Results page
List<IWebElement> elements = new List<IWebElement>();
elements.AddRange(driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"vn1s0p1c0\"]")));
```

Comment: Thanks for that. What I did was set the timeout to 0 before the FindElements then reset it to 60 afterwards as I still wanted to the timeout to have effect elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @MarkMasic : If you want to have waiting logic in some places, then you can use `WebDriverWait` which do not impact global driver timeout setting.

Comment: Just make sure you aren't using both implicit and explicit waits... that's [http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits](warned against in the docs). `WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.`